# Gecko web browser in C# does not release memory after I navigate to a new url

Tags: c#, memory, browser, gecko, xulrunner

I'm using C# and Gecko web browser to develop an application. I found that even there is only one GeckoWebBrowser on the form and navigate to some video pages again and again, the application will create more and more threads, and the application will crash after I switch these pages several times. Here are my c# codes:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "http://news.qq.com";
    string xulrunnerPath = "e:\\vm_tmp\\firefox\\xulrunner\\";
    Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(xulrunnerPath);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (null == browser)
    {
        browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
        Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Parent = this;
        this.Tag = browser;

        browser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 100);
        browser.Name = "webControl1";
        browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1280, 960);
        browser.TabIndex = 0;
        browser.Visible = true;
        browser.BringToFront();
    }

    browser.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
}
```

And here are my html codes:

```
    <body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px 0px;">
        <center>
            <video id="video" width="100%" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" loop="loop">
                <source src='movie/1.mp4' type='video/mp4' ></source>
            </video>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Do I need do any resource cleaning (In xulrunner or in GeckoWebBrowser) before I do navigate? I also test these pages in Firefox. When I begin to switch these pages, the Firefox also create more and more threads and eat more and more memory. But After several times, the Firefox will release some threads and memory. So the usage of memory increased very slowly. But I cannot find this situation in my C# application.

Comment: How do you declare `browser` variable?

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
if (null == browser)
{
    browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
    ...
}
else 
    browser.Stop();
```

Also this line can cause memory leaks:

```
Controls.Add(browser);
```

It seems that you are creating more than one instance of `GeckoWebBrowser` and that could be the problem. Be sure to dispose every instance properly:

```
//dispose the web browser control
browser.Dispose();
browser = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you let me know if the code below help with memory consumption?

After you initiate xulrunner, please try adding this timed event and the event handler:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer heapMinimizerTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            heapMinimizerTimer.Interval = (2 * 60 * 1000); // 2 mins
            heapMinimizerTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(heapMinimizerTimer_Tick);
            heapMinimizerTimer.Start();


  private void heapMinimizerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _memoryService = Xpcom.GetService<nsIMemory>("@mozilla.org/xpcom/memory-service;1");
            _memoryService.HeapMinimize(false);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I switched my application to CEF and didn't find similar problem. So now I'm working on CEF. I'll try your way several days later.